# CSS 3 slideshow not displaying in IE10

Tags: css, slideshow, internet-explorer-10, css-animations

So I'm trying to get this slideshow to work in IE10. According to W3Schools IE supports this syntax, but allthough it works fine on every other browser, IE just doesn't cooperate. 
I'd appreciate any hint on the matter...
This is how the code looks:

```
#image li.firstanimation {
    -moz-animation:anim 75s linear infinite;    
    -webkit-animation:anim 75s linear infinite;
    animation:anim 75s linear infinite;
}
#image li.secondanimation {
    -moz-animation:animtwo 75s linear infinite;
    -webkit-animation:animtwo 75s linear infinite;
    animation:anim 75s linear infinite;
}
#image li.thirdanimation {
    -moz-animation:animthree 75s linear infinite;
    -webkit-animation:animthree 75s linear infinite;
    animation:anim 75s linear infinite;
}
#image li.fourthanimation {
    -moz-animation:animfour 75s linear infinite;
    -webkit-animation:animfour 75s linear infinite;
    animation:anim 75s linear infinite;
}
#image li.fifthanimation {
    -moz-animation:animfive 75s linear infinite;
    -webkit-animation:animfive 75s linear infinite;     
    animation:anim 75s linear infinite;
}
#image li.sixthanimation {
    -moz-animation:animsix 75s linear infinite;
    -webkit-animation:animsix 75s linear infinite;      
    animation:anim 75s linear infinite;
}
#image li.seventhanimation {
    -moz-animation:animseven 75s linear infinite;
    -webkit-animation:animseven 75s linear infinite;        
    animation:anim 75s linear infinite;
}
#image li.eighthanimation {
    -moz-animation:animeight 75s linear infinite;
    -webkit-animation:animeight 75s linear infinite;        
    animation:anim 75s linear infinite;
}
#image li.ninthanimation {
    -moz-animation:animnine 75s linear infinite;
    -webkit-animation:animnine 75s linear infinite;     
    animation:anim 75s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes anim {
    0%  { top:0px; }
    1%  { top:0px; } 
    9% { top:0px; opacity:1; z-index:0; } 
    11% { top:325px; opacity:0; z-index:0; } 
    12% { top:-325px; opacity:0; z-index:-1; }
    97% { top:-325px; opacity:0; z-index:0; }
    98% { top:-325px; opacity:0; }
    100%{ top:0px; opacity:1; }

}
@keyframes animtwo {
    0%  { top:-325px; opacity:0; }
    9% { top:-325px; opacity:0; }
    11% { top:0px; opacity:1; }
    12% { top:0px; opacity:1; } 
    20% { top:0px; opacity:1; z-index:0; } 
    22% { top:325px; opacity:0; z-index:0; }
    23% { top:-325px; opacity:0; z-index:-1; } 
    100%{ top:-325px; opacity:0; z-index:-1; }
}
@keyframes animthree {
    0%  { top:-325px; opacity:0; }
    20% { top:-325px; opacity:0; }
    22% { top:0px; opacity:1; }
    23% { top:0px; opacity:1; } 
    31% { top:0px; opacity:1; } 
    33% { top:325px; opacity:0; z-index:0; }
    34% { top:-325px; opacity:0; z-index:-1; } 
    100%{ top:-325px; opacity:0; z-index:-1; }
}
@keyframes animfour {
    0%  { top:-325px; opacity:0; }
    31% { top:-325px; opacity:0; }
    33% { top:0px; opacity:1; }
    34% { top:0px; opacity:1; }
    42% { top:0px; opacity:1; z-index:0; }
    44% { top:325px; opacity:0; z-index:0; }
    45% { top:-325px; opacity:0; z-index:-1; }
    100%{ top:-325px; opacity:0; z-index:-1; }
}
@keyframes animfive {
    0%  { top:-325px; opacity:0; }
    42% { top:-325px; opacity:0; }
    44% { top:0px; opacity:1; }
    45% { top:0px; opacity:1; }
    53% { top:0px; opacity:1; z-index:0; }
    55% { top:325px; opacity:0; z-index:0; }
    56% { top:-325px; opacity:0; z-index:-1; }
    100%{ top:-325px; opacity:0; z-index:-1; }
}
@keyframes animsix {
    0%  { top:-325px; opacity:0; }
    53% { top:-325px; opacity:0; }
    55% { top:0px; opacity:1; }
    56% { top:0px; opacity:1; }
    64% { top:0px; opacity:1; z-index:0; }
    66% { top:325px; opacity:0; z-index:0; }
    67% { top:-325px; opacity:0; z-index:-1; }
    100%{ top:-325px; opacity:0; z-index:-1; }
}
@keyframes animseven {
    0%  { top:-325px; opacity:0; }
    64% { top:-325px; opacity:0; }
    66% { top:0px; opacity:1; }
    67% { top:0px; opacity:1; }
    75% { top:0px; opacity:1; z-index:0; }
    77% { top:325px; opacity:0; z-index:0; }
    78% { top:-325px; opacity:0; z-index:-1; }
    100%{ top:-325px; opacity:0; z-index:-1; }
}
@keyframes animeight {
    0%  { top:-325px; opacity:0; }
    75% { top:-325px; opacity:0; }
    77% { top:0px; opacity:1; }
    78% { top:0px; opacity:1; }
    86% { top:0px; opacity:1; z-index:0; }
    88% { top:325px; opacity:0; z-index:0; }
    89% { top:-325px; opacity:0; z-index:-1; }
    100%{ top:-325px; opacity:0; z-index:-1; }
}
@keyframes animnine {
    0%  { top:-325px; opacity:0; }
    86% { top:-325px; opacity:0; }
    88% { top:0px; opacity:1; }
    89% { top:0px; opacity:1; }
    98% { top:0px; opacity:1; z-index:0; }
    100%{ top:325px; opacity:0; z-index:0; }
}
```

Comment: Well you're first problem is that you listened to what W3CSchools said about something.  W3C Schools is not an officially supported site and is full of misinformation and inaccuracies.  Do NOT use them as a source of information.  Instead look here: http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-animation

Comment: Is that *all* of the relevant code? IE 10 doesn't [need the `-ms`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh673530(v=vs.85).aspx) prefix so your code should work fine. If that is not *all* of your code, please post the rest.

Comment: Can you please setup a http://jsfiddle.net of your problem so we can test better?

Answer (score 0):

Animation seems to work just  for me, here's the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yjsxp/

HTML:

```
<ul id="image">
    <li class="firstanimation">
     ...
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
#image { position: relative;}
#image li{
    position:absolute;
    background-color:red;
}
#image li.firstanimation {
    -moz-animation:anim 75s linear infinite;    
    -webkit-animation:anim 75s linear infinite;
    animation:anim 75s linear infinite;

}
@keyframes anim {
    0%  { top:0px; }
    1%  { top:0px; } 
    9% { top:0px; opacity:1; z-index:0; } 
    11% { top:325px; opacity:0; z-index:0; } 
    12% { top:-325px; opacity:0; z-index:-1; }
    97% { top:-325px; opacity:0; z-index:0; }
    98% { top:-325px; opacity:0; }
    100%{ top:0px; opacity:1; }
}
```